# How to filter specific endpoint for retry policy using Polly

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, polly, retry-logic

How to filter specific endpoint for retry policy using Polly

All client requests `MyServiceHttpClient` will retry. How disable retry policy specific api?

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyServiceHttpClient>(client =>
{
    /* configuration */
})
.AddPolicyHandler((serviceProvider, request) => 
    HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, 
            sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)), 
            onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
            {
                serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<MyServiceHttpClient>>()
                    .LogWarning("Delaying for {delay}ms, then making retry {retry}.", timespan.TotalMilliseconds, retryAttempt);
            }
            ));
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to split it in 2.

Comment: What you mean ?

Comment: I mean split `MyServiceHttpClient` into two, with different policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using no-op policy:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyServiceHttpClient>(client =>
    {
        /* configuration */
    })
    .AddPolicyHandler((serviceProvider, request) =>
        request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/api/") // your predicate
            ? Policy.NoOpAsync<HttpResponseMessage>() // <- no op for matching predicate
            : HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
                    sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
                    onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
                    {
                        serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<MyServiceHttpClient>>()
                            .LogWarning("Delaying for {delay}ms, then making retry {retry}.",
                                timespan.TotalMilliseconds, retryAttempt);
                    }
                ));
```

Or  another approach would be to repeat the `HandleTransientHttpError` logic but with adding corresponding filter.

Comment: Is is possible to set polly policy for existed IHttpClientBuilder (when use other library)?

Comment: @Rafael have not tried it. You can try to reregister that service with call `AddHttpClient` after the library register invocation.

Answer (score 1):

[Even though Guru Stron's proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76827647/13268855) works it is pretty hard to maintain IMHO.

Let me present you an alternative solution. The `WaitAndRetryAsync` has many different overloads. Some requires a `retryCount` parameters, while others don't. If you use an overload which requires a `IEnumerable<TimeSpan> retryDurations` parameter then you can do the following:

```
.AddPolicyHandler((serviceProvider, request) =>
    HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            GetRetryDelays(request), 
            (_, timespan, retryAttempt, __) =>
            {
                //logging               
            }));
```

Now lets see the related `GetRetryDelays` implementation

```
private static readonly Uri DoNotRetryUri = new("https://...");
private const int MaxRetryAttempt = 3;
private static IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetRetryDelays(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.RequestUri == DoNotRetryUri)
        return Array.Empty<TimeSpan>();

    return Enumerable.Range(0, MaxRetryAttempt)
        .Select(retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)))
        .ToArray();
}
```

- If the request uri is the same as the constant then it will not perform any retry
- If the request uri is different than the constant then it create an array of sleep durations with the following values

```
[
   00:00:01
   ,
   00:00:02
   ,
   00:00:04
]
```